# How can I copy files from Azure File storage to my local machine every 2 hours (periodically)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

Please suggest the best way to I copy data from Azure File storage to  local machines every 2 hours (periodically). Can we write a C# exe to do that and deploy it on the PC?

Answer (score 0):

Write a desktop application in any language with the SDK support of Azure File Storage. Within that application, create a timer to do your download through the API.

If the there are configurable settings or user interactions needed, I'd say go for a desktop application.

Otherwise, and if your clients are windows PCs, best way would be to write a [windows service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/walkthrough-creating-a-windows-service-application-in-the-component-designer) that does the job.

Comment: I can write Windows Service in c#. Can we connect to Azure File Storage using that.

Comment: I don't see why not.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps could use Azure Logic Apps - if you set a job to run periodically and copy files from File Storage to OneDrive, for example, then OneDrive would replicate your files onto a on-premise server.